# Realm PermissionManager.getPermissions() error after connection reset

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-java

I am facing this issue and would like to know if someone facing it too and maybe have solution.

I also opened issue on Github but no answer so far
[link to issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6492)

After connection reset or dropped connection `PermissionManager.getPermissions()` return this error:

> E/REALM_SYNC: Connection[4]: Reading failed: Connection reset by peer
>   E/REALM_JAVA: Error in __permission:
>   CONNECTION_RESET_BY_PEER(realm.basic_system:104): Connection reset by
>   peer E/REALM_SYNC: Connection[1](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6492): Reading failed: Connection reset by
>   peer E/REALM_JAVA: Error in __wildcardpermissions:
>   CONNECTION_RESET_BY_PEER(realm.basic_system:104): Connection reset by
>   peer E/REALM_SYNC: Connection[2]: Reading failed: Connection reset by
>   peer

In other words, after connection reset (even manually disable and enable network) it is not possible to get user's permissions anymore.

This issue have big impact on the our app, since we need to show/hide UI components based on this permissions.

Also, does `PermissionManager.getPermissions()`not support offline mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing and re-opening the `PermissionManager` should fix the issue (at least it does for me).

Comment: This is workaround for now, Realm is working to fix this issue, hope new version will released soon.